# Configure Single Sign On with federated Identity Providers via WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Logging in to an application using federated IDPs such as Google or Facebook with protocol OIDC/SAML
what we need to prepare for it, any advice?

example
XYZ application is an IdP (Identity Provider) like Google or Facebook 
1. XYZ application will be central user identity provider
2. Log in to another application with XYZ login credential
3. Log in to another application directly in the same browser (i.e. without being redirected to XYZ application)
4. we are using WSO2 IS version 5.10

Answer (score 0):

According to the description, XYZ is a Identity provider similar to Google or facebook. This XYZ has the user identities and you want to login to an application using this XYZ idp through the WSO2 IS.

WSO2 IS supported federated authentication using standard protocols such SAML, OIDC and WSFederation.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-federated-authentication/) to understand further on this identity federation. You can use the default [OIDC authenticator](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect/) or [SAML authenticator](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-saml-2.0-web-sso/) to add the XYZ as a federated IDP to WSO2 IS.

Comment: Thanks and nice information. Do you have an example of a php application with the OIDC / SAML protocol, because I'm confused to get started

Comment: I couldn't find any php samples. But you can find some samples related to other technologies here: github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/client-samples, github.com/wso2/samples-is/tree/master/sso-samples/